# Recommendation for C# Matrix Library

Tags: c#, matrix

I need a C# library to deal with matrices. It should implement singular value decomposition, matrix inversion, etc

I've used [CSML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19032/C-Matrix-Library) before, but this does not implement some of the features i need.

Some of the features are:
Singular value decomposition
Matrix inversion
Trace
Determinants

**Suggested Libraries (from answers)**

(most of them implement the features stated above)

- [Math .NET Numerics for .NET, Silverlight and Mono](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) (opensource)
- [Extreme Optimization Numerical Libraries](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/) (commercial, very
  complete)
- [IL Numerics](http://ilnumerics.net/$Home.html) (commercial)
- [Deltix's FinMath numerical library](https://rtmath.net/products/finmath/) (commercial,  uses the Intel®
  Math Kernel Library (MKL) and Intel® Integrated Performance
  Primitives (IPP))
- [Lightweight fast matrix class in C#](http://blog.ivank.net/lightweight-matrix-class-in-c-strassen-algorithm-lu-decomposition.html) (Strassen algorithm, LU
  decomposition)

Comment: It might help to mention the features that CSML doesn't have that you require.

Comment: http://accord-framework.net/ Implements matrix operations as extension methods of `double[,]` type.

Comment: closed as not constructive. 69,620 views.

Comment: Have a look at [NumSharp](https://github.com/SciSharp/NumSharp), it provides the .NET bindings of numpy.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) is very nice, if it supports the operations you want.  The older Math.Net Iridium still supports more options.  Also, [dnAnalytics](http://www.codeplex.com/dnAnalytics) is quite nice, but no longer being developed.  (It, as well as Iridium, are being merged into Math.NET Numerics.)

On the commercial side, there are some very good, robust options.  The [Extreme Optimization Numerical Libraries](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/) work very well.  The [Visual Numerics](http://www.vni.com/products/imsl/) library also works very well (although with a royalty-based distribution...).

Comment: Iridium will do the trick. I could'nt use the matrix class from Math.NET since it is abstract, so I needed to derive it. right ?

Comment: They provide concrete implementations, but since Math.NET Numerics isn't complete, some of the implementations aren't completed (yet).

Comment: There are two concrete classes: Matrix m = new DenseMatrix(...) or new SparseMatrix(...) depending on your needs.

Comment: I would also give shout out to dotNumerics which goes much beyond simple linear algebra. For example, it has optimizer like L-BGFS and differential equations solver, http://www.dotnumerics.com/NumericalLibraries/DifferentialEquations/Default.aspx

Comment: Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159385/dotnumerics-alglib-dnanalytics-math-net-f-for-numerics-mtxvec

Answer (score 8):

I believe that [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) has most of the features you mention. Yuu may want to look at it and see if it fits your needs.

You can take a look at the [Iridium samples](http://mathnet.opensourcedotnet.info/doc/IridiumCodeSamples.ashx?HL=matrix) to see the syntax and example code.

Answer (score 5):

I have been using [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net/) a lot. Also did some contributions to the project. It by know is the only library I know of, which does not spend half the CPU time in GC for [serious computations](http://ilnumerics.net/blog/fast-faster-performance-comparison-c-ilnumerics-fortran-matlab-and-numpy-part-ii). Its fast and mature. See the full [feature list](http://ilnumerics.net/%24FeatureList.html).

Comment: +1 ILNumerics has all the features of other libs. But it is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the libraries mentioned in other posts I can say a few warm words about [FinMath](https://rtmath.net/products/finmath/) library. It is rather new library, but according to my experience it has several advantages. It is very easy to use this library. First, it has only one executable file (*.dll) for both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems. Second, it is build on top of well-known Intel Math Kernel Library and therefore it provides very good performance. Managed .NET API provided by this library is also very extensive and flexible. But, it is proprietary software and costs considerable amount of money. It also lacks some functionality (e.g. compared to [NMath](http://www.centerspace.net/products/nmath/) from CenterSpace Software). Anyway, it worth time to try it.