# Creating and using a sparse matrix in Accord.NET

Tags: sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, adjacency-matrix, accord.net

I would appreciate any hint on how to generate a sparse matrix in Accord.NET or in C#, without creating a library from scratch. The problem is that I want to make a matrix of size 30k by 30k representing the adjacency matrix of a graph, which will be almost always sparse. Past 15000 rows or columns, the following code generates an error:

```
var A = new double[n, n];
```

error: Array dimensions exceeded supported range.

ps. I am aware of the [Sparse Class](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Math_Sparse_FromDictionary.htm) but as can be seen from the description, this class can only be used to make sparse vectors, not matrices.

If it is possible to make a sparse matrix, then the next immediate question is can it be treated like a normal matrix in Linear Algebraic operations, e.g. in subtracting two matrices, or finding a sub-matrix using:

```
Accord.Math.Matrix.Get(A, IVI, BVI, B);
```

Answer (score 0):

30kx30k isn't very much.. Try change in your project properties in "Build", "Prefer 32 bit" to unchecked, then you can also try this code:
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().MaxWorkingSet = new IntPtr(262144000);
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().MinWorkingSet = new IntPtr(209715200);
to your method, it may help if there is problem with memory to make this array.

Anyway you can use for this MathNet downloadavble via Nuget.
Exactly sparse matrix from *MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double*
MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.SparseMatrix M = new MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.SparseMatrix(30000);
This Math.Net look slow to me, Accord is better in some operations and I dont know how to do sparse matrix in Accord which I would rather use than MathNet.

Comment: Hi Ossj, thanks for your explanations! Unfortunately I do not have to the settings of the code editor that I have to work with. So, I cannot use the first suggestion. Re Math.Net, I myself have migrated my code from a previous version working with MathNet to Accord. Now i have hit a dead end realizing that Accord does not have sparse matrices. Disappointed with C# for numerical computing...

Comment: Oh.. Accord doesnt't have them :O shame on them.
Alglib is good and fast (but not free if comerrcial used) but its big machine.. Very small library and also good/fast is StarMath, it have sparse matrices too. :)

Comment: thanks for the tip! I also reached to the same conclusion to go for AlgLib :)

Comment: So, maybe you can help me with my problem in AlgLib :D 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588389/how-to-solve-rectangular-sparse-matrix-using-alglib-linlsqrsolvesparse

Comment: Ooh this is frightening... To be honest after some serious thinking, I decided to switch back to Math.NET considering its [relatively] friendly documentation; and previous successful use. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159385/dotnumerics-alglib-dnanalytics-math-net-f-for-numerics-mtxvec