# Creating a 3x3 matrix with user input numbers C#

Tags: c#

im trying to create a 3x3 matrix in c# language, i know how to create the matrix but i need help for user input numbers. I hope someone can help me thank you for that.

Comment: Console app/GUI app? What form do you want them to enter the matrix in?

Comment: Look up `Console.ReadLine` and `int.Parse`. I assume you know how to use a couple of nested `for` loops.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336701/recommendation-for-c-sharp-matrix-library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will add a while loop and use double.TryParse to validate user's input. Usin BWHazel's code:

```
const int MATRIX_ROWS = 3;
const int MATRIX_COLUMNS = 3;

double[,] matrix = new double[MATRIX_ROWS, MATRIX_COLUMNS];

for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_COLUMNS; j++)
    {
        double input;
        Console.Write("Enter value for ({0},{1}): ", i, j);
        while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter correct value for ({0},{1}): ", i, j);
        }
        matrix[i,j] = input
    }
}
```

To get the totals for all rows you can use following snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS; i++) 
{
    // The some for each row
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_COLUMNS; j++)
    {
        sum += matrix[i,j];
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.format("The sum for row {0} is: {1}", i, sum));
}
```

Comment: That work thank you, but now im trying to use for cycle to get the total of every row , if you can help me i'm really grateful. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "total of every row", but if you want to read all columns for a row on a single line, than you can use:
string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split() to get all the values and the parse the elements of the array.

Comment: i meant i want the total for every row like if row 1 have 1,2,3 i want the total of these numbers (1+2+3). Hope you did understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the command-line, something like this should work:

```
const int MATRIX_ROWS = 3;
const int MATRIX_COLUMNS = 3;

double[,] matrix = new double[MATRIX_ROWS, MATRIX_COLUMNS];

for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_COLUMNS; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter value for ({0},{1}): ", i, j);
        matrix[i,j] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

This assumes you are using `double` for the values.  The `.Parse()` method is available for all .NET numeric types including `int`.

Comment: That work thank you, but now im trying to use for cycle to get the total of every row , if you can help me i'm really grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtResult.Text=GenerateMatrix(Int32.Parse(txtRow.Text), Int32.Parse(txtColumn.Text));
    }
    private string GenerateMatrix(int Row,int Column)
    {
        string matrix = string.Empty;
        string Result = string.Empty;
        int nxtline=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
            {
                if (nxtline==Column)
                {
                    matrix = matrix + Environment.NewLine;
                    nxtline = 0;
                }
                matrix = matrix+"*";
                nxtline = nxtline + 1;
            }
        }

        Result = matrix;
        return Result;
    }
```