# how to create and multiply matrixes in c#

Tags: c#, matrix

Okay, so yesterday at school i was presented with a task in c#, which was create a program to build a Matrix and multiply that matrix by another one. so far i have done this:

```
 List<List<double>> translacao = new List<List<double>>();

            translacao[0][0] = 0;
            translacao[0][1] = 0;
            translacao[0][2] = 4;
            translacao[1][0] = 0;
            translacao[1][1] = 1;
            translacao[1][2] = 6;
            translacao[2][0] = 0;
            translacao[2][1] = 0;
            translacao[2][2] = 8;
```

I tried with normal arrays like double [,] , but my problem is always the same. From here, how can i multiply this Matrix by another ?? (I know how to multiply matrixes (in paper) but isnt there any method in c# that does that for me ?) the only Matrix classes i found were only able to multiply 3x3 matrixes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336701/recommendation-for-c-sharp-matrix-library

Comment: I doubt what your homework task was "find a c# library for multiplication matrixes and use it". It is more likely that your homework task is "implement matrixes multiplication in C# by yourself using algorithm you've learned".

Comment: On "paper" and on computer, it is the same logic, you just need to form an algorithm to do it. The "Art" of programming can only be mastered by reading few programming **books**. (no..not on google)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are gonna have to write your own funciton, maybe even a few overloads for different sizes depending on how crafty your function is.

*I am not very good at matrix math but here is somewhat of a process*

also this is not c#:

```
matrix Multiply[][] (matrix a[][], matrix b[][])
{
    //check the sizes, i remeber its something that must be done but dont remember the specifics
    if (a.width != b.height)
        throw WrongSizeException;

    matrix result[][];
    //do the math:
    result[0][0] = a[0][0] * b[0][0]; //again, I don't remeber this stuff
    ...
    ...
    return result;

}
```

I hope this gets the right gears turning