# Speed up nested for loops and improve performance

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop

I am working on a program and it has a pretty long execution time. I'am trying to improve performance where I can, however my knowledge is limited in this area. Can anyone recommend a way to speed up the method below?

```
public static double DistanceBetween2Points(double[,] p1, double[,] p2, int patchSize)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < patchSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < patchSize; j++)
        {
            sum += Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p1[i, j] - p2[i, j], 2));
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The method calculates the *distance* between two images by calculating the sum of all the distances between two points on the two images.

Comment: I am not sure what your routine is doing but have you tried removing the `Sqrt` and `Pow` operations and use `Abs` instead?

Comment: I haven't, I shall try that now. Do you happen to know a way to speed up for loops? As I'm pretty sure they are the reason why execution time is so slow

Comment: It is very strange calculation. What do you want to calculate? Can you explain your intent in more details?

Comment: I am searching and comparing different patches on an image. Basically it is for image recognition, give the two patches passed in (p1 and p2) I calculate each pixels distance from the original image and the comparison image. (Hope that makes sense)

Comment: @ConorShannon - well you seem to be sqrt a ^2 which is in effect just removing the `-` sign - but I can't see how what you are doing would achieve the aim stated of calculating distances (but sometimes we don't always have the big picture)

Comment: @ConorShannon - well I hope you have some test data with known 'inputs' 'results' to test your algorithm against.

Comment: The `Sqrt` op will probably be the slowest thing here not the loops nor the `Pow` - more context will help I think.

Comment: Are you sure you need input of double instead of int? What exactly is in those arrays?

Comment: How big is patchSize typically?

Answer (score 3):

1. Think about your algorithm. Probably a pixel-distance isn't the best thing to get an acurate image-distance.
2. replace `sqrt(x^2)` by `abs(x)` or even faster:

   ```
   if(x < 0) x = -x;
   ```
3. Rename your routine to OverallImageDistance or similar(will not improve performance) ;)
4. Use `unsafe` pointers, and calculate your distance in a single loop using these pointers:

   ```
   unsafe
   {
     sum = 0.0;
     int numPixels = patchsize*patchsize;
     fixed(int *pointer1 = &p1[0])
     {
       fixed(int* pointer2 = &p2[0])
       {

         while(numPixels-- > 0) 
         {
           double dist = *pointer1++ - *pointer2++;
           if(dist < 0) dist = -dist;
           sum += dist;
         }
   ...
   ```

This should be several times faster than your original.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this method is really weird and does not look like distance between pixels at all. But certainly you would want to use linear algebra instead of straightforward array calculations.

Image recognition, natural language processing and machine learning algorithms all use matrices, because matrix libraries are highly optimized for these kind of situations, when you need batch processing.

There is a plethora of matrix libraries in the wild, look here [Recommendation for C# Matrix Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336701/recommendation-for-c-sharp-matrix-library)

**EDIT**: Ok, thanks for feedback, trying to improve the answer...

You can use Math.Net Numerics open source library (install `MathNet.Numerics` nuget package) and rewrite your method like this:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;

public static double DistanceBetween2Points(double[,] p1, double[,] p2, int patchSize)
{
   var A = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(p1).SubMatrix(0, patchSize, 0, patchSize);
   var B = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(p2).SubMatrix(0, patchSize, 0, patchSize);

   return (A - B).RowAbsoluteSums().Sum();
}
```

Essentially, loops slow down your code. When doing batch processing ideally you should avoid loops at all.