# Performing array operations on a Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, aforge

I am attempting to migrate some code from an old python project into a current *C#* project.

The python code I am attempting to adapt applies a *sobel* filter to each of the *RGB* color channels in an image, and then uses some basic linear algebra to stitch the channel results together into a *grayscale* image of the isolated edges.

The problem that I am running up against is that whereas python makes it easy to treat images as simple numerical arrays, and so allows one to take slices of them and perform linear algebra operations on them willy nilly (*C#* is more finicky with regards to typing).

I need to do matrix multiplication of the results I get from running the *sobel* filter on individual image channels, but am unclear as to how to massage a bitmap into a form that will easily allow this.

I have seen stuff on converting to a `byte` *array* but am not sure this will work for my purposes.  I'd really just like a regular int or `float` *array* containing pixel values.

I could loop through the pixels and perform *bitwise* operations on them, but this is bound to slow things down so I was wondering if there was a good way to either perform *matrix* operations on a Bitmap or convert the Bitmap into a form that will be amenable to this.

I am not sure exactly how useful it would be, but if it helps illustrate what I am talking about, here is my python code:

```
image_array = numpy.float64(scaled_image)

R_x = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 0], [[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])
G_x = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 1], [[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])
B_x = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 2], [[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])

R_y = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 0], [[1, 0 , -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
G_y = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 1], [[1, 0 , -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
B_y = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 2], [[1, 0 , -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])

Jacobian_x = R_x**2 + G_x**2 + B_x**2
Jacobian_y = R_y**2 + G_y**2 + B_y**2
Jacobian_xy = R_x * R_y + G_x * G_y + B_x * B_y
D = numpy.sqrt(numpy.fabs((Jacobian_x**2) - (2 * Jacobian_x * Jacobian_y) + (Jacobian_y**2) + 4 * (Jacobian_xy**2)))
E = (Jacobian_x + Jacobian_y + D) / 2
Edges = numpy.sqrt(E)
```

And where I am so far with the equivilant C# code:

```
Bitmap newImage = resize.Apply(bmp);
Bitmap RedImage = extractRed.Apply(newImage);
Bitmap GreenImage = extractGreen.Apply(newImage);
Bitmap BlueImage = extractBlue.Apply(newImage);

Bitmap Rx = SobelX.Apply(RedImage);
Bitmap Gx = SobelX.Apply(GreenImage);
Bitmap Bx = SobelX.Apply(BlueImage);

Bitmap Ry = SobelY.Apply(RedImage);
Bitmap Gy = SobelY.Apply(GreenImage);
Bitmap By = SobelY.Apply(BlueImage);

***Where all my math would go.
   Jacobian_x = yadda yadda yadda***
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are working with `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in that example when you refer to `Bitmap`, you will want to use `Bitmap.LockBits()` method to get a pointer to the raw bits in the bitmap.  You can then either use unsafe code (faster, but you better know what you are doing) or copy the bitmap data to and from managed memory as byte arrays to manipulate it.

Here's the official documentation on `LockBits()` and they have a reasonable example (using the safe but slower copy-to-and-from managed memory technique)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Awesome! This looks like exactly what I’m looking for. I have to wait to get into work to test it but I’m 99% sure this was what I needed. Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Ok so I'm accepting this answer so you get the points since its the most relevant answer here and the most likely to help others in similar general cases.  It ended up being problematic for me however so I ended up just looping through the image and making the modifications pixel by pixel.  I'll post that as an answer in case someone needs it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go to a lower level in C# and write the correlations yourself.

First of all, you'll have to retrieve the [colors for each pixel in the Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Bitmap_GetPixel_System_Int32_System_Int32_), and build a matrix with all that info.

> **Bitmap.GetPixel(Int32, Int32)**
>
> *Gets the color of the specified pixel in this Bitmap.*
>
> public System.Drawing.Color GetPixel (int x, int y);

Then correlate and multiply the matrixes. In order to achieve that, you can refer to a [third-part library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336701/recommendation-for-c-sharp-matrix-library) (like NumPy in the Python world) or do it by hand.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Util {
    public static Color[][] ExtractColorArrayFrom(Bitmap bm)
    {
        int height = bm.Height;
        int width = bm.Width;
        var toret = new Color[height][];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
            toret[ i ] = new Color[ width ];
            
            for(int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
                toret[ i ][ j ] = bm.GetPixel( i, j );
            }
        }
        
        return toret;
    }
    
    public static int[] ARGBFrom(Color c)
    {
        return new int[]{ c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B };
    }
}
```

Comment: The correlations/convolutions are already done. That’s what the sobelx and sobely functions do.  It’s atiching together the grayscale images that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, Tim's answer above about locking the bits is tremendously useful as a general solution for this kind of problem.  For reasons I won't get into here however, since the problems are very specific compatibility issues with some of my external dependencies, it didn't end up working for me.  I ended up doing what I said I didn't want to do and looping through the image to do my math.  It still worked in the end and didn't slow the program by an amount noticeable to the user.  This may not be generally true however, as optimizing for speed is not a top priority of this particular application but is for many others that perform similar operations.  I ended up creating arrays of doubles of the same size as my image arrays, and then running my math on those arrays.  Once all the math was done, I used SetPixel to loop through a blank image and apply those pixel values to a new bitmap.

```
Bitmap RedImage = extractRed.Apply(newImage);
Bitmap GreenImage = extractGreen.Apply(newImage);
Bitmap BlueImage = extractBlue.Apply(newImage);

Bitmap Rx = SobelX.Apply(RedImage);
Bitmap Gx = SobelX.Apply(GreenImage);
Bitmap Bx = SobelX.Apply(BlueImage);

Bitmap Ry = SobelY.Apply(RedImage);
Bitmap Gy = SobelY.Apply(GreenImage);
Bitmap By = SobelY.Apply(BlueImage);
double[,] JacobianX = new double[Rx.Width, Rx.Height];
double[,] JacobianY = new double[Rx.Width, Rx.Height];
double[,] JacobianXY = new double[Rx.Width, Rx.Height];
double[,] Determinant = new double[Rx.Width, Rx.Height];
double[,] E = new double[Rx.Width, Rx.Height];
Bitmap Edges = new Bitmap(Rx.Width, Rx.Height);

for (int i = 1; i < Rx.Width-1; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 1; j < Rx.Height-1; j++)
        {
        Color redX = Rx.GetPixel(i, j);
        Color greenX = Gx.GetPixel(i, j);
        Color blueX = Bx.GetPixel(i, j);

        Color redY = Ry.GetPixel(i, j);
        Color greenY = Gy.GetPixel(i, j);
        Color blueY = By.GetPixel(i, j);

        JacobianX[i, j] = Math.Pow(redX.R, 2) + Math.Pow(greenX.G, 2) + Math.Pow(blueX.B, 2);
        JacobianY[i, j] = Math.Pow(redY.R, 2) + Math.Pow(greenY.G, 2) + Math.Pow(blueY.B, 2);
        JacobianXY[i, j] = redX.R * redY.R + greenX.G * greenY.G + blueX.B * blueY.B;
        D[i, j] = Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(Math.Pow(JacobianX[i, j], 2) - (2 * JacobianX[i, j] * JacobianY[i, j]) + (Math.Pow(JacobianY[i, j], 2)) + 4 * Math.Pow(JacobianXY[i, j], 2)));
        E[i, j] = (JacobianX[i, j] + JacobianY[i, j] + D[i, j]) / 2;

        if (Math.Sqrt(E[i, j]) > 255) { E[i, j] = Math.Pow(255,2); }

        Color newcolor = Color.FromArgb(255, (int)Math.Sqrt(E[i, j]), (int)Math.Sqrt(E[i, j]), (int)Math.Sqrt(E[i, j]));
        Edges.SetPixel(i, j, newcolor);
    }
}
```

It was a rather marked improvement:

[image: Sobel On Grayscale Image]

*Sobel on Grayscale (Default using Aforge library)*

VS.

[image: Sobel on Color Image]

*Sobel on Color (Using the code above)*